How to use useNavigate() in ReactTS in a Class / Event
I've been having the problem that I can't navigate through components, I always get Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
YES, I know the hook rules of React, I know how it would work, but unfortunately this does not solve my problem.
My problem is that I have one and one EventHandler to handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {} because I have a <form>, this goes against the hook rule of React, but still I can only decide in this event if it can be directed to the dashboard or to the error page.
My question is: Is there a way to make this possible or a completely different solution?
//the imports of the Login component
import React from "react";
import { Button, Card, Checkbox, Label, TextInput } from "flowbite-react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEye, faEyeSlash } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons";
import { faArrowLeft, faArrowRightToBracket } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";


//the properties of the Login component
interface LoginProps { }

//the state of the Login component
interface LoginState {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    remember: boolean;
}

//the Login component
export default class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps, LoginState> {
    constructor(props: LoginProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    //init the state of the component with empty/default values
    state = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        remember: false,
    }

    //called after the component was rendered
    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/backgroundDesk.jpg")';
        document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
        document.body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
    }

    //called after the component was unrendered
    componentWillUnmount() { }

    //called after the component was updated
    handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const target: EventTarget & HTMLInputElement = event.target;
        const value: string | boolean = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name: string = target.name;

        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    //handle the login
    handleLogin = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        //deactivate the default form submit behavior (like reloading the page, put the data in the url, etc.)
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);

        //logic can be added here to check the login credentials

        const navigate = useNavigate();
        navigate("/dashboard");
    }


    //toggel the password visibility
    handelToggelPassword = () => {
        //get the password input field
        const passwordInput: HTMLElement | null = document.querySelector('input[name="password"]');
        const icon_passwordEyeVis: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("icon_passwordEyeVis");
        const icon_passwordEyeInvis: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("icon_passwordEyeInvis");

        if (!passwordInput) {
            console.error("Password input field not found in the DOM for toggeling the password visibility");
            return
        }

        if (!icon_passwordEyeVis || !icon_passwordEyeInvis) {
            console.error("Password eye icon not found in the DOM for toggeling the password visibility");
            return
        }

        if (passwordInput.getAttribute("type") === "password") {
            passwordInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
            icon_passwordEyeVis.style.display = "none";
            icon_passwordEyeInvis.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            passwordInput.setAttribute("type", "password");
            icon_passwordEyeVis.style.display = "block";
            icon_passwordEyeInvis.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    //render the component
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="flex">
                    <img src="/invoices-manager-logo.png" className="size-28 m-6" />
                    <label className="text-white font-bold text-5xl flex items-center justify-center">Invoices Manager</label>
                </div>
                <div className="centerDiv">
                    <h1 className="text-5xl text-center font-semibold mb-5 text-white">Login</h1>
                    <Card className="min-w-max bg-opacity-65">
                        <form className="flex flex-col gap-4" onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                            <div>
                                <div className="mb-2 block">
                                    <Label className="text-xl" value="E-mail:" />
                                </div>
                                <TextInput name="username" type="email" className="text-xl" placeholder="max@mustermann.de" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleInputChange} required autoFocus />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div className="mb-2 block">
                                    <Label className="text-xl" value="Password:" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="flex">
                                    <TextInput name="password" type="password" className="flex-grow mr-2" placeholder="******" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleInputChange} required />
                                    <Button onClick={this.handelToggelPassword} className="w-1/12 pr-5 pl-5">
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon id="icon_passwordEyeVis" icon={faEye} size="xl" />
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon id="icon_passwordEyeInvis" className="hidden" icon={faEyeSlash} size="xl" />
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex items-center gap-2 mb-2">
                                <Checkbox name="remember" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                <Label className="text-base">Remember me</Label>
                            </div>
                            <Button type="submit" className="text-2xl">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRightToBracket} size="xl" className="mr-2" />
                                Sign in</Button>

                            <Link to="/register" className="text-blue-600 font-medium">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} size="xl" className="mr-3" />
                                Sign up</Link>
                        </form>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

